# Menu add using include loads on top of page and hides page's content

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML page where I use `include` to add an horizontal menu. But when I do this it loads on top of the page and the page's content gets hidden and I have no idea why.

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php include 'MenuAdminstrador.php';?>

<!--from here on, all gets hidden behind the menu-->

    <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

included file code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<?php 
?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>SPYKA</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="templatemo">
    <!-- 
    Medigo Template
    http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_460_medigo
    -->

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700,400italic,700itali" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,500,200,100,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/misc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue-scheme.css">

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>          <!-- Menu Responsive -->
    <div class="responsive_menu">
        <ul class="main_menu">
            <li><a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="FormularioVerUsuarios.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Usuarios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FormularioAMUsuario.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Clientes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="FormularioVerClientes.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Clientes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FormularioAMCliente.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Facturas</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="FormularioVerFacturas.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Facturas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FormularioFactura.php" target="Pantalla">Facturar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="FormularioVerProductos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FormularioAMProducto.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grupos de Productos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="FormularioVerGrupos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Grupos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FormularioAMGrupo.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><label style="color: #800080; font-weight:bold;">Perfil</label></a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php" target="_parent"><label style="color: red; font-weight:bold;">Salir</label></a></li>
        </ul> <!-- /.main_menu -->
    </div> <!-- /.responsive_menu -->

    <header class="site-header clearfix">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">



                    <div class="pull-left logo">
                        <a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Medigo by templatemo">
                        </a>
                    </div>  <!-- /.logo --> 
                                                <!-- Menu PC -->

                    <div class="main-navigation pull-right">

                        <nav class="main-nav visible-md visible-lg">
                            <ul class="sf-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">Inicio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioVerUsuarios.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Usuarios</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioAMUsuario.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Clientes</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioVerClientes.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Clientes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioAMCliente.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Facturas</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioVerFacturas.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Facturas</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioFactura.php" target="Pantalla">Facturar</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioVerProductos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Productos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioAMProducto.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Grupos</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioVerGrupos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Grupos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="FormularioAMGrupo.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#"><label style="color: #800080; font-weight:bold;">Perfil</label></a></li>
                                <li><a href="logout.php" target="_parent"><label style="color: red; font-weight:bold;">Salir</label></a></li>
                            </ul> <!-- /.sf-menu -->
                        </nav> <!-- /.main-nav -->

                        <!-- This one in here is responsive menu for tablet and mobiles -->
                        <div class="responsive-navigation visible-sm visible-xs">
                            <a href="#nogo" class="menu-toggle-btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div> <!-- /responsive_navigation -->
                    </div> <!-- /.main-navigation -->

                 <!-- /.col-md-12 -->

            </div> <!-- /.row -->
<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['NombreRepresentante']?></h2>
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </header> <!-- /.site-header -->

    <script src="js/min/plugins.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/min/medigo-custom.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

output:

[image: output]

Comment: Please show us the code inside the included file.

Comment: It could also be helpful to see the final html output, after PHP has been processed.

Comment: added included file code

Comment: That explains a lot. If you take a look at the final HTML output, it should be very clear what is happening. The contents of the included file is placed where you put the include call. This means that your final HTML document has multiple html and body elements. That's a big no-no. Since you close both the body element and the html element inside of the included file, the browser will assume that nothing more should be shown on the page. You can either place the included file inside an iframe (probably a bad idea) or refactor your code (much better).

Comment: Take the head-element from your included file and place it inside the original file instead. Remove the doctype, html and body tags from the included file and keep only the contents of the body element.

Comment: I have submitted an answer that shows what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include an entire HTML document complete with its own doctype and html tag inside of an included file when you already have an established HTML structure in the including file.

You need to do some refactoring:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>SPYKA</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="templatemo">
        <!-- 
        Medigo Template
        http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_460_medigo
        -->

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700,400italic,700itali" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,500,200,100,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/misc.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue-scheme.css">

        <!-- JavaScripts -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'MenuAdminstrador.php';?>

        <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p>Some more text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the included file:

```
<!-- Menu Responsive -->
<div class="responsive_menu">
    <ul class="main_menu">
        <li><a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="FormularioVerUsuarios.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Usuarios</a></li>
                <li><a href="FormularioAMUsuario.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clientes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="FormularioVerClientes.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Clientes</a></li>
                <li><a href="FormularioAMCliente.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Facturas</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="FormularioVerFacturas.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Facturas</a></li>
                <li><a href="FormularioFactura.php" target="Pantalla">Facturar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="FormularioVerProductos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="FormularioAMProducto.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Grupos de Productos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="FormularioVerGrupos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Grupos</a></li>
                <li><a href="FormularioAMGrupo.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><label style="color: #800080; font-weight:bold;">Perfil</label></a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php" target="_parent"><label style="color: red; font-weight:bold;">Salir</label></a></li>
    </ul> <!-- /.main_menu -->
</div> <!-- /.responsive_menu -->

<header class="site-header clearfix">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">



                <div class="pull-left logo">
                    <a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Medigo by templatemo">
                    </a>
                </div>  <!-- /.logo --> 
                                            <!-- Menu PC -->

                <div class="main-navigation pull-right">

                    <nav class="main-nav visible-md visible-lg">
                        <ul class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="Administrador.php" target="_parent">Inicio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioVerUsuarios.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Usuarios</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioAMUsuario.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clientes</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioVerClientes.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Clientes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioAMCliente.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Facturas</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioVerFacturas.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Facturas</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioFactura.php" target="Pantalla">Facturar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioVerProductos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Productos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioAMProducto.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grupos</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioVerGrupos.php" target="Pantalla">Ver Grupos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="FormularioAMGrupo.php" target="Pantalla">Ingresar o Modificar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><label style="color: #800080; font-weight:bold;">Perfil</label></a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php" target="_parent"><label style="color: red; font-weight:bold;">Salir</label></a></li>
                        </ul> <!-- /.sf-menu -->
                    </nav> <!-- /.main-nav -->

                    <!-- This one in here is responsive menu for tablet and mobiles -->
                    <div class="responsive-navigation visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <a href="#nogo" class="menu-toggle-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- /responsive_navigation -->
                </div> <!-- /.main-navigation -->

             <!-- /.col-md-12 -->

        </div> <!-- /.row -->
        <h2><?php echo $_SESSION['NombreRepresentante']?></h2>
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</header> <!-- /.site-header -->

<script src="js/min/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/min/medigo-custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work, the page loads exactly the same way it was before

Comment: @ErrolChavesMoya Alright. Check the HTML source code on the page to make sure that the h1 and p-tags from your main document appear there. If they do and they don't show, you probably have a CSS issue. If they don't then there is probably another error related to your PHP code. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared document type, html, head and body in the current file.  Your imported file (MenuAdminstrador.php) also contains those elements. An html page should contain only one doctype, html, head and body.

Remove the doctype, html, head and body elements and keep only the contents of body element of your MenuAdminstrador.php file.

But in this case you have to include the links of google fonts, CSS and JavaScript in the head element of the current file.

If you don't prefer that method, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a MenuHead.php that contains the contents of the external file's head element.
2. Create a MenuBody.php that contains the contents of the external file's body element.
3. Import the MenuHead.php into the head of current file.
4. Import the MenuBody.php into the body of current file.